# How to send a mail later in mac Mail app, before macOS Ventura macOS 13

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I wish to compose and send email later in macOS Mail.app, before macOS Ventura macOS 13.

Currently i can't see any mail app utility to achieve this. As explained here, [Send later is not available beforemacOS Ventura macOS 13](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254481264?sortBy=best).

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the link, mail app doesn't have this functionality before macOS Ventura macOS 13.

The work-around I'm currently using requires *iPhone with send later capability* and that *same mail is registered in iOS mail app*.

1. Draft your mail in your Macbook
2. Save as draft
3. Go to your iPhone, see your drafts
4. Now you can schedule your mail

Comment: This is better than my solution of virtualizing the newer OS on older OS.